# Preserve null values in array of Play framework form mapping

Tags: arrays, forms, scala, playframework, option-type

I'm trying to get an idea how can I force Play Scala framework form mapper to save null values in array property.

Example. Request body (print out of snippet below):

```
AnyContentAsJson({
"entities":["ENI","GDF Suez","Procter & Gamble"],
"entityValues":[null,"42",null]
})
```

Resulting value of `entityValues` property after binding:

```
List(Some(42.0))
```

But I want to see:

```
List(None, Some(42.0), None)
```

Code snippet of controller:

```
def actionX = Action {implicit request =>
  println(request.body)
  TaskForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest("error")
    },
    taskData => {
      println(taskData.entityValues)
    }
  )
}
```

Form class with mapping:

```
case class TaskForm(entities: List[String],
                entityValues: List[Option[Double]]) { }

object TaskForm {
  val map = mapping(

    "entities" -> list(text),
    "entityValues" -> list(optional(of(doubleFormat)))

  )(TaskForm.apply)(TaskForm.unapply)

  val form = Form(
    map
  )
}
```

I also tried some combinations of `optional` and `default` mapping parameters, but a result is still the same.

Using `0` or any another numeric value instead of `null` is not a case.

Does anyone have any ideas how to implement such form behaviour?

Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're sending JSON to a form endpoint. While this *will* work for simple JSON structures, you get no control over how it is done and hence get problems like the one you're seeing.

I'd be explicit about being a JSON-endpoint, and then you can define your own `Reads[Option[Double]]` that works **precisely how you want it to**:

First, define the implicits at the Controller level; here's where we get to control the `null`-handling; it ends up being pretty easy:

```
implicit val optionalDoubleReads = new Reads[Option[Double]] {
  def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
    case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(Some(n.toDouble))
    case JsString(n) => JsSuccess(Some(n.toDouble))
    case JsNull      => JsSuccess(None)             // The important one
    case _           => JsError("error.expected.jsnumber")
  }
}

implicit val taskReads = Json.reads[TaskForm]
```

With that done, we modify your `Action` to *require* JSON (using `parse.json`). The function itself remains remarkably similar to the original form-binding `fold`:

```
 def actionX = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>

   println(request.body)
   request.body.validate[TaskForm].fold(
     jsonErrors => {
       BadRequest(s"Error: $jsonErrors")
     },
     taskData => {
       println(taskData.entityValues)
       Ok(taskData.entityValues.toString)
     }
   )
 }
```